# Why does quanteda's textmodel_wordfish run infinitely when I apply to quanteda.corpora's corpus of UK party manifestos?

Tags: r, nlp, quanteda

I'm attempting to apply wordfish to quanteda.corpora's data_corpus_ukmanifestos, but it never seems to stop running. On the other hand, when I use the example code from quanteda's wordfish tutorial, wordfish is complete within seconds. Is this just a problem for me? Does this happen to others as well? How can I circumvent this problem?

This is the code I have right now. Like I said, wordfish works in seconds when run on the Irish budget speeches, but never stops running when applied to party manifestos.

```
## install/load packages
## install.packages(c("quanteda", "devtools"))
## devtools::install_github("quanteda/quanteda.corpora")
library(quanteda)
library(quanteda.corpora)
require(quanteda)
require(quanteda.corpora)
dfmat_irish <- dfm(data_corpus_irishbudget2010, remove_punct = TRUE)
tmod_wf <- textmodel_wordfish(dfmat_irish, dir = c(6,5))
summary(tmod_wf)

dfmat_uk <- dfm(data_corpus_ukmanifestos, remove_punct = TRUE)
wf_uk <- textmodel_wordfish(dfmat_uk, dir = c(83, 74))
```

How do I get wordfish to work with this corpus?

Answer (score 0):

Try trimming low-frequency words.  The longer the time span of a time-series corpus, the more sparse your matrix.  There are 101 manifestos in the UK corpus, going back to 1945.  A lot of the terms are going to be very rare.

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 1.4.4
## Parallel computing: 2 of 12 threads used.
## See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.
## 
## Attaching package: 'quanteda'
## The following object is masked from 'package:utils':
## 
##     View
data(data_corpus_ukmanifestos, package = "quanteda.corpora")
system.time(
  wf_uk2 <- dfm(data_corpus_ukmanifestos, remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_punct = TRUE) %>%
    dfm_trim(min_termfreq = 10, min_docfreq = 20) %>%
    textmodel_wordfish(dir = c(83, 74))
)
##    user  system elapsed 
##   2.274   0.124   2.356
```

You could also use `dfm_wordstem()` to reduce the feature set further, but best to do this before the trim operation.

Comment: Thanks so much, this resolved the issue! I'm also curious -- does quanteda have an in-built means of removing stop words?

Comment: See `?stopwords`.